# X11 intervene while moving and resizing windows

Tags: c, linux, x11, xlib, xcb

How can I intervene programmatically while moving and resizing windows? (XCB solution preferred)

Eg. I want to implement magnetic windows a la winamp.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

not possible from app itself, something like magnetic windows is implemented at window manager level

Applications may communicate some of this behaviour via [EWMH](http://standards.freedesktop.org/wm-spec/wm-spec-latest.html) but anything outside of ewmh spec is only possible when you have direct control over window manager behavior

Comment: Hi Andrey, looks like we meet again in the not-possible-land of Linux :)